# What is the mass of 1 atom of carbon?

Tags: physical-chemistry, mole

I know that relative atomic mass of $\ce{^{12}C}$ is $12~\mathrm{u}$.

Therefore mass of $1~\mathrm{mol}~\ce{C} = 12~\mathrm{g}$
\begin{align}
 \text{mass of }6.022\cdot 10^{23} \text{ C atoms} &= 12~\mathrm{g}\\ 
 \text{mass of }1 \text{ C atom} &= \frac{12~\mathrm{g}}{6.022\cdot10^{23}}\\
&=\boxed{1.99\cdot10^{-23}~\mathrm{g}},\\
\end{align}

but

\begin{align}
 1~\mathrm{u} &= 1.66\cdot10^{-24}~\mathrm{g}\\
\implies \text{Mass of }1~\ce{^{12}C}\text{ atom} &= 1.66\cdot 12 \cdot 10^{-24}~\mathrm{g}\\
&= 19.92\cdot 10^{-24}~\mathrm{g}\\
&= 1.992\cdot 10^{-23}~\mathrm{g}.\\
\end{align}

Which is correct?

Also what is dimension formula of relative atomic mass, molar mass?

Why is unit of molar mass $\dfrac{\text{gram}}{\text{mole}}$ and not just $\text{gram}$ Since when has this $\text{mol}$ become a unit? It's just a number.

Comment: The number in the rectangle was off by 46 orders of magnitude!  (Sign error: should have been $10^{-23}$ not $10^{23}$ as it was originally.)  I'm edited it to be correct, presuming it was just a typo, but let me know if you have any confusion about why.

Comment: The mole became a **SI** unit in [1971](http://www.bipm.org/en/CGPM/db/14/3/).

Comment: Thank you both! @NicolauSakerNeto actually it was just a typo! the question was about which approach is correct? some of my friends were saying that second approach is dimensionally incorrect.

Comment: Sorry if my previous comment seemed condescending, I should have realized it was a typo but recently I commented a question involving an incorrect exponent sign and that led me astray.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both approaches are correct.

[Avogadro's number is](http://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?na%7Csearch_for=physchem_in!) $6.02214129\times 10^{23}$ and represents the number of carbon-12 atoms in 12 grams of unbound carbon-12 in the ground electronic state.

$12$grams$/6.02214129\times 10^{23} = 1.9926467\times 10^{-23}$grams

The [unified atomic mass unit (u) is](http://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?tukg) $1.660538921 \times 10^{-24}$ grams

$12 \times 1.660538921 \times 10^{-24}$ grams $ = 1.9926467\times 10^{-23}$grams

Comment: The [Avogadro constant](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00543.html) has a unit: $L = 6.022 141 79 30 \cdot 10^{23}~\color{red}{\mathrm{mol}^{−1}}$.

Comment: The difference between the Avogadro constant (dimensional) and Avogadro's number (dimensionless) is quite subtle, and often overlooked.